# Move to trash problem in Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: keyboard-layout, delete, trash, layout

It's been three days that if I cancel a file or if I click "Move to trash" the file doesn't disappear but it goes at the bottom of the folder's list. If i close and reopen the folder there's no more a file and it's on the trash. So the file is actually deleted but it remains visible on the folder until you close and reopen it.

Comment: Do you move to trash while respective file is open?

Answer (score 3):

This is actually due to bugs that appear in Nautilus 44.0. So to fix the problem you can just upgrade Nautilus to the latest version available [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus).

**Note:** As of today they have Nautilus 44.2.1 but it's still in proposed state so to install you have to [allow **Pre-released updates (lunar-proposed)**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yHJI.png) and then upgrade by

> sudo apt install nautilus=1:44.2.1-0ubuntu1

After you input the command you will see that the dependencies' versions are miss match so you have to manually install each dependency by specifying their version as shown above.

**Alternate Solution:** You just have to wait until the package is marked as released and then you just install it by

> sudo apt install nautilus

And with this your problem will be solved.

Comment: Very nice answer, works great, if someone is looking which packages are needed, here's my list:
libgtk-4-1_4.10.4+ds-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
libgtk-4-1_4.10.4+ds-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libgtk-4-dev_4.10.4+ds-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libgtk-4-common_4.10.4+ds-0ubuntu1_all.deb
gir1.2-nautilus-4.0_44.2.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
gir1.2-gtk-4.0_4.10.4+ds-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libnautilus-extension4_44.2.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libnautilus-extension-dev_44.2.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
nautilus-data_44.2.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb
nautilus_44.2.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb

I downloaded and installed all together using `dpkg -i *.deb`