# Deleted files are moved to end of folder temporarily. Disturb the selection focus?

Tags: delete, 23.04

Title: Issue with file deletion behavior in Ubuntu 23.04 x86_64

I am currently using Ubuntu 23.04 x86_64, and I have noticed a recent change in the way files are handled when I delete them. Previously, deleted files would simply disappear from the folder, but now they are **moved to the end of the folder** and subsequently sent to the trash when I refresh. This behavior was not present before.

However, the more concerning issue is that every time I delete a file, it is moved to the end of the folder and selected. As a result, I have to locate the next file after the one I deleted.

I regularly delete a large number of files, and this new behavior disrupts my workflow as it shifts my selection focus to the last deleted file, which is quite annoying.

I would appreciate it if someone could help me understand why this is happening and provide guidance on how to fix it.

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Cannot reproduce this (but then I am currently on Fedora with Files 44.2.1 (please include version of files in your question). Files was overhauled with the move to GTK4, so this certainly may be (one of the) bug(s). I found a file selection would after a while disappear or change when returning to an open Files window.

Comment: 44.0 , see the image above , if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As vanadium said it's a bug in Nautilus 44.0 so to upgrade it you can check [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1471732/1703722).