# Nautilus (Files) issue on latest updates for 23.04, nautilus 44.0 'scrambling' displayed files in files pane

Tags: nautilus

I'm not sure I even know how to describe this bizzare behavious from Nautilus (files).  Was working fine until updates about five daays or so ago. Problem started after the update then, and an update last night did not resolve it.

Basically, if I delete or move a file from the files pane in Nautilus, the wrong file disappears.  If I use the back arrow and then the forward arrow to go back to the same location, the file I moved or deleted is gone, and the one that disappeared previously is there.  If i move 4 files, 4 other files (not the right ones) disappear.   If I refresh by using the back and then forward arrow, everything is correct.

So, if I have:

file1.pdf
file2.pdf
file3.pdf
file4.pdf

and I delete **file2.pdf**, I am left with

file1.pdf
file2.pdf
file3.pdf

displayed in the file pane, which is wrong.  But if I use the arrows at the top of the window to go back, and then forward (ending up in the same folder as I started) I see

file1.pdf
file3.pdf
file4.pdf

displyed in the file pane, which is correct.

**It's driving me bonkers.**  Help!

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** I've experienced a similar issue, and though I haven't identified any open bugs reported that describes this functionality, I'd suggest that you either kill the Files process (`sudo pkill nautilus`), reboot, or run package updates. My own issues appear to have disappeared over the past day or two. Best of luck.

Comment: I have the same problem since a few days. And rebooting does not solve it. Running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` was done, and currently it returns `The following packages have been kept back:
  dkms gdm3 gir1.2-gdm-1.0 gir1.2-gtk-4.0 libcupsfilters2 libcupsfilters2-common libgdm1 libgtk-4-1 libgtk-4-bin libgtk-4-common
  libgtk-4-media-gstreamer libppd2 libppd2-common openssh-client
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.`

Answer (score 0):

I realized no problem after upgrading to 23.04, but Files started to have these weird issues after some updates to Ubuntu. But it seems so be problems in Files and I hope it will get resolved soon: [Move to trash problem in Ubuntu 23.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1471026/move-to-trash-problem-in-ubuntu-23-04/1471732#1471732).